# How to filter NA values and estimate them by applying a mean on the past records in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the following manner. Now I'm trying a method to estimate the values for NAs and -999 values in the A column.

I want to do this by taking a mean of existing previous 10 year values (5 above and 5 below) of that particular month that's having NA or -999 values. And I've this data for many, many IDs.

```
ID     L1  L2  Year    Month   R   A
1234    89  65  2003    Jan     11  76
1234    89  65  2003    Feb     34  86
1234    89  65  2003    Mar     6   30
1234    89  65  2003    Apr     7   76
1234    89  65  2003    May     8   43
1234    89  65  2003    Jun     90  67
1234    89  65  2003    Jul     65  13
1234    89  65  2003    Aug     54  98
1234    89  65  2003    Sep     3   67
1234    89  65  2003    Oct     22  0
1234    89  65  2003    Nov     55  127
1234    89  65  2003    Dec     66  74
1234    45  76  2004    Jan     67  3
1234    45  76  2004    Feb     87  2
1234    45  76  2004    Mar     98  65
1234    45  76  2004    Apr     5   78
1234    45  76  2004    May     4   44
1234    45  76  2004    Jun     3   53
1234    45  76  2004    Jul     77  NA
1234    45  76  2004    Aug     8   98
1234    45  76  2004    Sep     99  79
1234    45  76  2004    Oct     76  -999
1234    45  76  2004    Nov     56  23
1234    45  76  2004    Dec     4   65
```

Example: To estimate the 'A' column's NA (or -999 sometimes) value for July 2005, I want to take a mean of the remaining 10 years' values of July month (five values above 2005 and five below it) for each unique ID value.

```
ID     L1  L2  Year    Month   R   A
1234    45  76  1998    Jul     45  35
1234    45  76  2001    Jul     33  25
1234    45  76  2002    Jul     45  34
1234    45  76  2003    Jul     43  56
1234    45  76  2004    Jul     56  54
1234    45  76  2005    Jul     77  NA
1234    45  76  2006    Jul     88  33
1234    45  76  2008    Jul     76  28
1234    45  76  2009    Jul     65  40
1234    45  76  2011    Jul     43  45
1234    45  76  2013    Jul     12  32
```

So, I need to filter ID and month name and bring out records for 10 years for the month that is having NAs or -999 values, and then apply mean on those 10 values to replace this NA or -999. The data is huge.

How do I achive this in R?

Comment: Care to make a reproducible example? This is fairly straightforward and a simple loop can be constructed to find and replace each NA.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
indx = which(is.na(df$A))
for(i in 1:length(indx)){
  subdf = df[which(df$ID == df$ID[indx[i]] & 
                   df$Month == df$Month[indx[i]]),]
  temp = which(subdf$Year == df$Year[indx[i]])
  subdf$Year = unique(subdf$Year)
  subdf = subdf[which(subdf$Year >= (subdf$Year[temp]-5) & 
                     subdf$Year <= (subdf$Year[temp]+5)),]
  df$A[indx[i]] = mean(subdf$A, na.rm=T)
}
```

I'm sure there is a more beautiful way to do this. By suggestion you might also want to run

```
df$A[which(df$A <= -999)] = NA
```

before executing the code shown above.

Comment: Hello @mts. I suspect that the "=" should be replaced with "==" in your solution.

Comment: @RHertel true and thanks, edited it. Downfalls of not having reproducible data to run code on. There's one more thing amiss here, some years are without records, so I'll implement another step.

Comment: It's really much easier to work with reproducible data. If I may add another comment, I think that your `indx` vector should include also the cases where df$A=-999. 
Anyway, I suspect that the question is now answered to a good extent.

Comment: @mts Sorry I was away. Just checked it.. Although it didn't completely suffice the situation, which I guess is due to other inconsistencies in the data, the solution gave me an idea of how to appraoch the problem. Thank you so much for that.